# How to format Blazor code correctly in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor

How can you force Visual Studio Code to format blazor (.razor) files correctly?

Setting lanquage mode to: aspnetcoderazor does not format the code, however set to html completely corrupts the formatting of the @code block.

I would like to both types of code to be formatted correctly for each code type (HTML and C#).

Comment: Do you have the `C#` extension installed? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: I didn't get any extension for same, now I switch back VS19 with my favorite extension http://www.codemaid.net/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting Razor Files in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235450/formatting-razor-files-in-visual-studio-code)