# VS Code: How to enable .CSS intellisense for ASP.NET .cshtml files?

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-code, razor, intellisense

I have installed the "HTML CSS Support" extension for VS Code but it only seems to work on files with extension .html.  I can't get it to work with .cshtml files unless I rename the file temporarily to html but that's cumbersome.

What's the best way to enable VS Code to provide intellisense for local and remote .css files for use in .cshtml files?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235450/formatting-razor-files-in-visual-studio-code) post can help you

Comment: That worked @Empiire!  I used the second approach in that post, which was creating commands to change the language back and forth between HTML and aspnetcorerazor.  If you want to post a formal answer around the solution proposed by Kia.g in that post I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to associate *.cshtml* files to *html* formatter, you can insert the following snippet in your *settings.json* file:

```json
  "files.associations": {
    "*.cshtml": "html"
  }
```

that way vscode treats *.cshtml* files like *html* file and you should be able to use formatters and intellisense in those files.

---

Besides, you can use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235450/formatting-razor-files-in-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-56086296) using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.change-language-mode) to change the *language-mode-setting* of vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I added "aspnetcorerazor" in my local settings.json via the extention-settings.

```
    "css.enabledLanguages": [
    "html",
    "aspnetcorerazor"
],
```

I added a local file with the following in .vscode/settings.json

```
{
"css.styleSheets": [
    "/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "/wwwroot/css/site.css",
    "/wwwroot/ProjectName.styles.css"
]
```

}

You can read about this in the "HTML CSS Support" extention details.